# Can firebase functions make a http request to a Compute Engine instance within the same project without an external IP?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I need to make http requests from a firebase function to a gcloud virtual machine instance that has only internal IP address. Both are in the same project Id and in the same region, but I am not sure if they are in the same zone.

Comment: No, private networking is not yet available for Cloud Functions.

Comment: Sounds like an answer Michael. :-)